# How to close same activity. which is open multiple time?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have two `activities`. one activity contains multiple fragments inside that `fragment` I open another activity(second activity). My second activity contains a folder name list. when I click on the folder list item the same activity is open with the subfolder list. and again click on the subfolder list it navigates to the same activity with its subfolder list. Now when I choose the folder's list file then I want to finish all the second `activity` that I open on click.

I also try using `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` but it will `finish` all activities instead of the only second activity.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
android:launchMode="singleTask" //use this for your activity in manifest and
```

here are some important lines from android documentation

The `singleTask` and `singleInstance` modes also differ from each other in only one respect: A `singleTask` activity allows other activities to be part of its task. It's always at the root of its task, but other activities (necessarily "standard" and `singleTop` activities) can be launched into that task. A `singleInstance` activity, on the other hand, permits no other activities to be part of its task. It's the only activity in the task. If it starts another activity, that activity is assigned to a different task — as if `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` was in the intent.

Answer (score 1):

there is no need to open same activity multiple times you can use

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

in Manifest like this :

```
<activity android:name=".SavedFormActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"/>
```

Comment: I try android:launchMode="singleInstance" but activity open only one time. when i click on folder list then activity not open again.

Answer (score 1):

**add this in your manifest file in activity**

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
android:launchMode="singleTask"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just call `finish()` after every Intent.

**Edit :**

If you want back functionality try this way when you want to remove all back stack `Activities` add `flags` with that Intent like this

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

In your case when you choose folder's list file just add flags `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` and `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` with `intent` all previous back stack `Activities` will `finish`.

Comment: i want back functionality. so i can't use finish every time.

Comment: only close last one remaining stay as it is.

Answer (score 0):

**use this**

```
 if (isTaskRoot()==false ) {
        finish();
        return;
    }
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it's always a good idea to explain what your code does.